# How to split jQuery variables to be processed with .on() in paralell?

Tags: jquery

At the beginning, I tried to merge similar variables, to be *simultaneously* (in paralell) processed with a bunch of similar jQuery methods. Used .merge([ ]) as a try, and got unwanted *sequential* execution.

The code:

```
var $title = $('[id^=title-]');
var $postmeta = $('[id^=meta-]');
$([$title, $postmeta]).each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/./g, "<span>$&</span>").replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;"))
    .on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
    if (isInView) {
        // do inbound things
    }
    else {
        // do outbound things
    }
  });
});
```

*note: I took a piece of jQuery from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126451/splitting-text-into-individual-characters-for-animation) (that code is similar, but this question is more precise).*

**Now I need** to split the output, in order each variable was passed to `.on()` in paralell, but with previously granted attributes.

Edit: added snippet.

```css
/*
 CSS Reset
*/
   html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,audio,video,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark {
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
#title-, #meta- {
    position: relative;
}
#title- span, #meta- span  {
 position: relative;
 display:inline-block;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inview/1.0.0/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $title = $('[id^=title-]');
    var $postmeta = $('[id^=meta-]');
    $([$title, $postmeta]).each(function(){
     $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/./g, "<span>$&</span>").replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;"))
     .on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
        if (isInView) {
          TweenMax.staggerFromTo( $($title).find("span"), 0.4, {autoAlpha:0, rotationX:-90, top:"-30px"}, {autoAlpha:1, rotationX:0, top:"0px"}, 0.1 );
          TweenMax.staggerFromTo( $($postmeta).find("span"), 0.09, {autoAlpha:0, scale:2}, {autoAlpha:1, scale:1}, 0.01 );
          
        }
     else {
TweenMax.staggerFromTo( $($title).find("span"), 0.4, {autoAlpha:1, rotationX:0, top:"0px"}, {autoAlpha:0, rotationX:-90, top:"-30px"}, 0.1 );
TweenMax.staggerFromTo( $($postmeta).find("span"), 0.09, {autoAlpha:1, scale:1}, {autoAlpha:0, scale:2}, 0.01 );
       }
      });
      });
      
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="title-1">This is title 1</div>
    <div id="title-2">This is title 2</div>
    <div id="meta-1">To start animation, click Run. </div>
    <div id="meta-2">Then click here, or resize the height of this window (simulate 'inview' event). </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: *`in order each variable was simultaneously passed to .on()`* can you expand on that?

Comment: well, each variable, after being processed, has to be passed to .on() in paralell (not queue) with another variable ( title || meta , with attributes and conditions granted by previous methods) ...not as a merget set of variables as it is now